# Image tags display in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: html

I just set up my website on Namecheap, which I built in HTML and Twitter Bootstrap.

I am using the following tag for images

```
<img src="images\myimage.jpg">
```

This works fine in Chrome and in Firefox if I open it locally, but from my domain, the images don't show up in Firefox. It's still working fine in Chrome. I even tried this and got the same result:

```
<img src="file://localhost/images\myimage.jpg">
```

I just tried Fiddler2 and I get 404 messages that say under the url `http://myurl.com/images%5Cmyimage.jpg`

EDIT:
I just figured it out my code was accident a "\" instead of "/" which only affected firefox, thanks for all the help

Comment: Are you hosting it locally or on a remote server?

Comment: When I host locally it works fine, when i host on my remote server, namecheap, it does not... That is only with firefox, chrome and IE always work

Comment: What does Firebug say about the image?

Comment: When the images are not serving in Firefox, if you look in Fiddler2, is Firefox even issuing requests for the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<img src="images/myimage.jpg" alt="" />`

/ instead of \, also close the image tag and add the `alt`-attribute or your HTML will not validate.

Edit:
Appearantly the `/>` is not mandatory, but the `alt` is...

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is good

```
<img src="images/myimage.jpg">
```

you simply need to add a folder name *images* in the same folder where your html is stored. Make sure you got the file you are looking for in your *images* folder

edit : I just saw your new comment. Try adding an `alt` attribut to your image like this

```
<img src="images/myimage.jpg" alt="The image isn't showing">
```

At least you will know if the browser got the tag correctly

Comment: I'm using that line right now and there is a folder named "images". It works perfectly using the same code in IE and Chrome just not firefox

Comment: Firefox is a ****** when it come time to debug... Have you tryed to clear the cache?

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot, i meant i cleared it and it still isnt working. And this entire bug is weird

Comment: I figured it out i twas my stupid mistake which i made twice by correcting it when i posted the tag here but not realizing it. I was using a \ instead of a /

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I wrote it incorrectly in my original question but the "\" should have been a "/". This only affected firefox

Comment: Post it wrote the correct way so it can benefit other people :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem, so if it's showing the image in chrome and not in firefox open your Html file in chrome and right-click on the image and copy the link address use the same link address in the img src.